# Automated Spinner Selection in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest

I am developing an android which has 4 spinners(A,B,C,D).
What I want to achieve is
If Spinner A is set to a value I want the remaining spinners to automatically change their value depending on the value of A

Like if I set Movie(in A)--->Ticket(in B)---->Place(in C)---->Time(D) to automatically fill in.

Thanking you
ChinniKrishna Kothapalli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set an OnItemSelectedListener to your Movie Spinner. The [Spinner tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) is an adequate example. Your OnItemSelectedListener may be like this:

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("firstMovieName")) {
            // set spinner B/C/D with the corresponding information of first movie
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

The onItemSelected method above may be too simple for your need.  You need figure it out how to link the four spinners yourself, but May it helps :)